# How do I embed downloaded mp4 video into react app?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have mp4 video inside my component folder but when I am trying to render a video it seems blank and I dont understand why

```
{this.state.showVideo && 
  <video width="320" height="240" controls className="video" autoPlay>
<source src='./video.mp4' type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will use one of react components? For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player or https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-react (https://video-react.js.org/)